# Granularity issue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three tables geography, sector and sales:

[image]

when I test the results:

[image]

Expected results: how to correct it?

[image]

I put an example of pbix file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnEAuCTkPRNnFk9fFBsD4Ke8fhCxmqb6/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: can you explain why you expect these numbers? as far as I can see, your current results are correct and there is nothing wrong with them.

Comment: @RADO there is duplicate salesid for each sector level 3.but when I need to do report for sector level 1 I need to get sum distinct values for amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create DAX measure:

```
No duplicates Sales = 
SUMX(
   SUMMARIZE(sales, sales[DATE], sales[AMOUNT], sales[geo level 3], sales[sector level 3]),
   sales[AMOUNT]
)
```

It will summarize only distinct vales.

However, consider removing sale ids and de-duplicating sales table in Power Query. It's a better solution.